# Custom Taxonomy Archive Pages in TwentySeventeen Theme

Tags: wordpress, taxonomy

I'm fairly familiar with PHP and have been working on a project that requires custom post types and custom taxonomies (tags). I'm using a child theme of TwentySeventeen as well as a custom plugin. Does anyone know how to create a custom tag specific template for this theme?

Comment: Check out the "Template Hierarchy", this is how WordPress looks up what templates to render for what: https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/basics/template-hierarchy/#tag

Comment: Thanks for the fast reply. I copied archive.php from the parent theme to the child theme, but still aren't able to load the tag's archive page

Comment: You'd probably need to rename it so WordPress knows it is supposed to use a different template for that archive. Something like `taxonomy-foo.php` where `foo` is the name of your taxonomy,